# Windows Script Componets - Are they thread safe

Tags: scripting

I need to develop a very simple class developed as a Windows Script Component that needs to work in a multi-threaded environment.
I am wondering just how thread safe Windows scripting Components are and the scripting engine that executes those components.
In VB6 if a compiled DLL was not compile with "Retain In Memory" and "Unattended Execution" set definately caused problems in a multi threaded environment, I experienced this 1st hand and spent weeks trying to locate the issue with a 3rd party DLL.
Would anyone happen to know what way Windows Scripting Component works, are they intrinsically thread safe (once we don't do anything non-thread safe in the components we write).

I realize that the Windows Script Components are COM Apartment threaded and may not be the most performant things in the world but I have no choice about this.

Kind Regards

Noel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we're found under exterme load testing that WSC components are perfectly thread safe.